# Empty property that should not be empty

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to display a ChatView if it is selected from the following code. But I only get to see the ProgressView, although I know for sure that this should not happen. Here is my code:

```
struct ChatListView: View {
    
    @State private var shouldShowChatCreationScreen = false
    @State private var chatUser: User?
    @State private var shouldNavigateToChatView = false
    @State private var chatForView: ChatModel?
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ChatListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(viewModel.chats) { chat in
                    ChatListCell(chat: chat)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            shouldNavigateToChatView = true
                            chatForView = chat
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Chats")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        shouldShowChatCreationScreen.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $shouldShowChatCreationScreen) {
                ChatCreationView(didSelectUser: { user in
                    print("did select user \(user)")
                    chatUser = user
                    shouldNavigateToChatView.toggle()
                })
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shouldNavigateToChatView) {
                if let user = chatUser {
                    ChatView(oppUser: user)
                } else if let chat = chatForView {
                    ChatView(chat: chat)
                } else {
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Print statement that make me sure that the first case in the fullscreencover should activate:

did select user User(id: "XYhspARpFdh8vb7tNYYssvvQBBG2", fullname: "Bowser", email: "bowser@bowser.de", username: "bowser", profileImageUrl: Optional("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/--------blurred for security reasons ---------"), bio: Optional(""), conversations: Optional([]))

I have tried using it without the if let, but since a user is an optional return this did not help here

Comment: When would you expect to see `ProgressView` in the full screen cover? It seems like it would never be shown. You always set either `charForView` or `chatUser` when presenting the full screen cover.

Comment: It may not be your issue, but you should never use `@ObservedObject` where the object is owned -- you need to use `@StateObject`

Comment: @Sweeper : This the point i donˋt expect to see it, but yet it is there when the view should appear. I have the Progress View in there bc it can happen in a rare case that chatForView or chat User is nil

Comment: So in "a rare case that chatForView or chat User is nil", you just show a full screen cover of a progress view, making the user unable to do anything? Or do you mean there is a case where `charForView` and `chatUser` is initially nil, but is going to be set to non-nil after the full screen cover appears?

Comment: @Sweeper if one of both is nil, there is a Progreesbar for now, later on the user should be able to dismiss it and then take further action. And the later is also the case it could very well be that the chat or user is nil until it is fetched from firebase

Comment: @Icon45 You would need to give more details than that for the "both `nil`" case, perhaps in a separate question. My answer still stands though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just explicitly capture both `chatForView` and `chatUser`, it should work:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shouldNavigateToChatView) { [chatUser, charForView] in
    if let user = chatUser {
        ChatView(oppUser: user)
    } else if let chat = chatForView {
        ChatView(chat: chat)
    } else {
        ProgressView()
    }
}
```

That said, this is a use case for `fullscreenCover(item:)`, assuming `ChatModel` and `User` are `Identifiable`. This overload presents the full screen cover when `item` is not nil.

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $chatUser) { user in
    ChatView(oppUser: user)
}
.fullScreenCover(item: $chatForView) { chat in
    ChatView(chat: chat)
}
```

Now you don't need `shouldNavigateToChatView`.

Other notes:

`viewModel` should be `@StateObject`:

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = ChatListViewModel()
```

When setting `chatForView` or `chatUser`, remember to set the other one to `nil`, e.g.

```
chatForView = chat
chatUser = nil // also do this
```

---

If there is a case where `chatForView`/`chatUser` are received later, but you want to show the full screen cover first, it'd better to model the three situations with an enum:

```
enum ChatInfo: Hashable, Identifiable {
    case chat(ChatModel)
    case user(User)
    case loading(SomeInfo)

    var id: ChatInfo { self }
}

...

@State chatInfo: ChatInfo?

...

.fullScreenCover(item: $chatInfo) { info in
    // ChatView will decide what to do in each case
    // e.g. in the case of .loading, display a progress 
    // indicator and use SomeInfo to fetch things.
    ChatView(info)
}
```